# Add blank line between two lines of text in webcal event's description

Tags: webcal

How to add blank line between two lines of text in webcal event's description? This \n\n doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you would provide a full iCalendar stream but, assuming you encoded them correctly, using "\n" is the only way to express intentional line break. Did you try to display your event using different clients ?